# How do I write a method using a particular class

Tags: java, object, methods, task

So I'm trying to write a method using linked lists called

```
public void insert(Task t)
```

I'm not quite sure how to write that method but I do know how to write a similar method called

```
public void insert(int index, int value)
```

which looks like this:

```
public void insert(int index, int value) throws ListException {
    int i = 0;

    if (index > getLength()) {
        throw new ListException("Index beyond bounds");
    }

    IntegerListNode prev = null;
    IntegerListNode curr = head;

    while (curr != null) {
        if (index > i) {
            i++;
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    IntegerListNode newNode = new IntegerListNode(value);
    newNode.next = curr;

    if (prev == null) {
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        prev.next = newNode; 
    }

    System.out.println(this);
}
```

What this method does is it inserts a value in a linked list at a specified index. What I'm supposed to do is write a similar method but instead of using integer objects, I'm supposed to use a class called task. Here's what the class looks like.

```
public class Task {
    int priority;
    int number;

    Task(int priority, int number) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.number   = number;
    }
}
```

So how am I supposed to call the method and what do I put in the method.

EDIT: Here's the tasklistnode that I wrote:

```
class TaskListNode {
    int priority;
    int number;
    TaskListNode next;

    TaskListNode(int priority, int number) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.number   = number;
        this.next     = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's a Task? (It's not something that's part of Java!)

Comment: If you are not specifying an index to insert into what is the desired behaviour? should the task be inserted at the beginning or end or does the Task object have a field stating the index it should be at?

Comment: I just found I'm supposed to use the task class (which I've updated in my post) but I'm still not sure how it works with the insert method.

Comment: @BrandonMacLeod Sounds like some custom class your professor has provided to you. People here won't know what that Task class is.

Comment: seems to me that the priority would be corresponding to the index and the number field of your Task class corresponds to the value in your insert method.

Therefore your new insert method could be calling insert(t.priority, t.number), provided that the linkedlist is correctly adapted

Comment: I'm just wondering where do I put the value and the index for the insert method because the task class doesn't specify any particular number for those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** Although some information seems missing, sometimes well written code (reasonably named variables, methods and classes) can serve as good documentation. I am leaping towards some conclusions based on it.

---

**Given:**

- A linked list implementation which supports random `insert`.
- A class named `Task` with a `priority`.
- `ListException` is thrown when `index` is supplied, but not thrown when `Task` is supplied.

**Probable use case:**

A priority list of tasks (`Task` objects stored in linked list sorted by `priority`).

---

**Solution:**

- Create class `TaskListNode` similar to `IntegerListNode`.
  *It should accept a `Task` in its constructor.*
- Write `public void insert(Task t)` method just like the one you have written.
  *Since index is not specifically supplied, it can't throw a `ListException`.*
- Remove bounds checking code.
  *No `index` => No `ListException`.*
- Edit the loop (that you used to traverse the linked list till the `index` is reached) such that it traverses the linked list till you find lower priority `Task` than the specified `Task`.
  *High priority `Task`s should be ahead in the list.*

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: I think I know what you're saying but I'm confused as to how you find the index and value (mainly calling the method). To call the method for integerlist I used list.insert(0, 31) but with the task linked list, how am I supposed to use the task t in order to get the index and the value? Also I wrote the tasklistnode which will be included for my linked list.

Comment: Don't *call* the existing function. Copy it's body into `void insert(Task t)` and edit it as I have suggested above.